# SPI or A0/A1: what is the best solution for pin allocation on an Arduino shield?

Tags: arduino-uno, pins, spi

When you design an Arduino shield you want to make it compatible with a maximum number of shields that may be stacked with it on an Arduino (UNO). Considering the following two possible tradeoffs, which one would you consider the best:

- **Option A**: A shield that uses pins A0 and A1, where no other stacked shield can use those pins.
- **Option B**: A shield that uses SPI, where other stacked shields can only use pins 11, 12 and 13 in SPI mode.

Note: I'm asking this question for a project I'm designing called [Omzlo one](http://omzlo.com/one). It's an Arduino compatible board with builtin CAN bus networking. I'm hesitating between two prototype designs.

Comment: Why not support both options with a set of switches (or jumpers) on the shield? The your Arduino library would have an input argument to indicate which option to use.

Comment: I would guess that a shield wanting to use SPI is more likely to do so as a slave...

Comment: @Edgar Bonet - I incorrectly said "SPI master mode"in the question. Corrected that.

Comment: it probably depends on the shield, and what other shields you expect it to combine with.